# How to show image preview when uploading an image using Vue js?

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm trying to show a preview image when a user uploads an image. For some reason my code works when I use an `<input>` with regular Bootstrap class of `form-control`, but when I use Bootstrap-Vue's `<b-form-file>` I get an error: `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"`

Data:

```
data() {
            return {
                options: [
                    { text: "Full Time", value: "Full Time" },
                    { text: "Part Time", value: "Part Time" },
                ],
                profileData: {
                    photo: '',
                    employment_type: "Full Time",
                    date_of_birth: "",
                    experience: "",
                    skills: "",
                },

            };
        },
```

my method:

```
methods: {
            attachImage() {
                this.profileData.photo = this.$refs.profilePhoto.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
                    this.$refs.profilePhotoDisplay.src = reader.result;
                }.bind(this), false);

                reader.readAsDataURL(this.profileData.photo);
            },
        }
```

Bootstrap Code, this code works:

```
<div role="group" class="form-group">
                        <label for="photo" class="d-block">Upload Profile Photo (optional)</label>
                        <div v-if="profileData.photo.name">
                            <img src="" ref="profilePhotoDisplay" class="w-100px" />
                        </div>
                            <input
                                id="photo"
                                v-on:change="attachImage"
                                ref="profilePhoto"
                                type="file"
                                class="form-control"
                            >
                    </div>
```

Bootstrap-Vue Code, this gives me the error:

```
<div v-if="profileData.photo.name">
                        <img src="" ref="profilePhotoDisplay" width="140" />
                    </div>
                    <b-form-group label="Upload Profile Photo (optional)" label-for="image">
                        <b-form-file
                            id="photo"
                            v-on:change="attachImage"
                            ref="profilePhoto"
                            type="file"
                        ></b-form-file>
                    </b-form-group>
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `v-model` with the `<b-form-file>` component? You can still use the same logic, but simply watch changes to the `v-model` instead.

Comment: But then how can I attach the method on there attachImage? Or I can still keep that just add the v-model?

Comment: You can still keep it, if you don't want to use a watcher on the component data that is used in the `v-model` binding.

Comment: How would that look exactly? Sorry I’m new to Vue.

Comment: Your broken example tries to access `profileData.image`, but there's no such property in `profileData`. The working example uses `profileData.photo`, which does exist.

Comment: That's me copy and pasting the wrong code. I just changed that to ```profileData.photo``` in my post. Even with this I get the error listed above. ```Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"```. So that doesn't solve my issue.